# clear cmd input in C

Tags: c, windows, input, cmd

For example, I run the program:

```
int a = 0;
while(a < 1000000000){
    a++;
}
```

and at this moment I'll type into the terminal:

```
a\na\na\na\na\na\n
```

Obviously, the text I entered will not be read, so when the program stops, I get something like this:

```
'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I clear this input and is it possible at all?

I tried writing after this loop
`fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);`
or
`while(getchar() != EOF);`
but in the second case it waits for EOF and I didn't provide it,
and it also shows that I entered something:

```
C:....>test
a
a
a
a
a
```

help me with this question and I would like to add that besides the standard libraries I can use <windows.h>

Comment: Do not tag "C" and "C++" at the same time when you have a "C" question.

Comment: And it is absolutely unclear WHAT you are trying to do. your `int a` has nothing to do with the name of your executable. So I am not surprised `a` is not recognized by your command prompt.

Comment: That's simply how most terminals work. Can you please tell us why this is a problem?

Comment: @PepijnKramer: They want to clear the terminal input buffer of all pending input.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: i know, `int a` used only for example, it can be `int i` or something else. my question was whether I could clear pending input entered during this while. I don't want to read it for something, I just want to clear it so I don't get something like: `'a'` (or "j" doesn't matter) `not recognized as an internal command...`

Comment: While you still haven't told us why this is a problem (making your question an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)), perhaps one of [the Windows console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) could help? Or perhaps use [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) in some non-blocking way to read everything from the standard input handle, until there's nothing more to read?

Comment: @Some programmer dude: ok, i use ll_keyboard hook and to not exit msg loop when i need user to input text i handling it myself in hook callback. so when the program stops, I get a bunch of calls consisting of text entered by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call `FlushConsoleInputBuffer` just before you exit the program:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    while(a < 1000000000){
        a++;
    }
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)); // last thing you do
}
```